# Can I use my XBox in China?

Tags: china, electronic-items, power

Im going to China soon and want to bring my Xbox One. How will I connect it to the outlets there? Is there a way to connect it to the outlets there?

Comment: The device should be marked with an input voltage and frequency range.  What does it say?

Comment: Lazy question, answers are all over the internet. You also have to check if everything works though the Chinese firewall(s).

Answer (score -1):

So if you do end up brining your Xbox, I'm already guessing you are coming out of the United States, but if so you will need to find an adapter which you could connect your Xbox one power cord into to, or you could go ahead and buy a Xbox one power cord over in China, but like I said previously, there are also adapter which you can use instead of having to buy a new one but it's your choice.